# Pixelated Video with Processing

Tags: java, video, processing, video-processing

I'm trying to load a video and then display it in a pixelated manner. It worked one time after loading for very long time, but then it stopped working - just a black screen and nothing comes up and without error message I wonder what goes wrong. Thanks.

```
import processing.video.*;
Movie movie;

int videoScale = 8;
int cols, rows;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  background(0);
  movie = new Movie(this, "movie.mp4");
  movie.loop();

  cols = width / videoScale;
  rows = height / videoScale;
}

void draw() {
  movie.loadPixels();

  for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
     int x = i * videoScale;
     int y = j * videoScale;
     color c = movie.pixels[i + j * movie.width];
     fill(c);
     noStroke();
     rect(x, y, videoScale, videoScale);
   }
  } 
}

// Called every time a new frame is available to read
void movieEvent(Movie movie) {
  movie.read();
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say it stopped working? Do you see an error? Some strange behavior? What behavior is that?

Comment: @KevinWorkman No, there is no error. It's just a black screen. There was one time, the video came up after a long period of time because I forgot to close it. Then I thought it was because the loading time too long, so I tried again, but nothing came up.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my question.

Comment: Can you post the video somewhere and link to it ? (Does it play back fully at least once ?)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Well, it really doesn't matter which video it is. I was just testing something out, and tried multiple ones, and none worked. So it can be any video of 640 x 360 really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be sampling from the wrong place here:

```
color c = movie.pixels[i + j * movie.width];
```

First off, `i` is your cols counter, which is the x dimension, the `j` is the rows counter, y dimension.
Secondly, you probably want to sample at the same scale, and therefore need to multiply by `videoScale`. You already have the `x,y` variables for that, so try sampling like this:

```
color c = movie.pixels[y * movie.width + x];
```

Alternatively, you can use a [PGraphics](https://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html) instance as a frame buffer to draw into at a smaller scale (resample), then draw the small buffer at a larger scale:

```
import processing.video.*;
Movie movie;

int videoScale = 8;
int cols, rows;
PGraphics resized;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  background(0);
  noSmooth();//remove aliasing

  movie = new Movie(this, "transit.mov");
  movie.loop();

  cols = width / videoScale;
  rows = height / videoScale;

  //setup a smaller sized buffer to draw into
  resized = createGraphics(cols, rows);
  resized.beginDraw();
  resized.noSmooth();//remove aliasing
  resized.endDraw();
}

void draw() {
  //draw video resized smaller into a buffer
  resized.beginDraw();
  resized.image(movie,0,0,cols,rows);
  resized.endDraw();
  //draw the small buffer resized bigger
  image(resized,0,0,movie.width,movie.height);
}

// Called every time a new frame is available to read
void movieEvent(Movie movie) {
  movie.read();
}
```